# Error in reading webservice result using KSoap library in android

Tags: android

I am using Ksoap library to read xml from a webservice.Following is my code that i have used :

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION_Transaction = "http://tempuri.org/Trackdata";
    private static String NAMESPACE_Transaction= "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String METHOD_NAME_Transaction = "Trackdata";
    private static String URL_Transaction = "https://devraj.charge.com/process/getAndroidData.asmx?WSDL";
```

I am calling showdetails() method using asyn task.

```
   public void showdetails()
        {
            String result = "";
            SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = null;
            SoapObject resultRequestSOAPbody =null;
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE_Transaction, METHOD_NAME_Transaction);

            request.addProperty("Type","payment");
            request.addProperty("Id",53);
            request.addProperty("amount","0.02");
            request.addProperty("CCExpMonth",11);
            request.addProperty("CCExpYear",22);
            request.addProperty("Source","gg");
            request.addProperty("profileId",748);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL_Transaction);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;

            try 
            {
                androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION_Transaction, envelope);
                String requestDumpString = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
                System.out.println("requestDump : " + requestDumpString);
                resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); // Output received
                result = resultRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString(); // Result string
                 System.out.println("OUTPUT : " + result);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

However i am getting the following error:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

At this statement:
resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); 
Can somebody tell me what can be the error i have parsed other webservices as well that worked fine however for this one i am getting this error.
Following is part of my xml data :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ClsProcessData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <ProfileId>748</ProfileId>
  <Id>53</MerchantId>
  <InvoiceNum>53-375</InvoiceNum>
  <InvoiceDescription />
  <amount>0.02</InvoiceAmount>
  <CCName />
  </ClsProcessData>
```

Any help will be appreciated.Will be thankful if some one can tell me the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
String responseLocal = resultsRequestSOAP.toString();
```

Try the above instead of  resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

```
 if (envelope.bodyIn instanceof SoapFault) {
    String str= ((SoapFault) envelope.bodyIn).faultstring;
    Log.i("", str);
} else {
    SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
    Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(resultsRequestSOAP));
}
```

Alternatively if your response is primitive try

```
 SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: I tried it.It gives me error- at this line resultRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;.java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject

Comment: It entered into the if condition ...str=--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Cross check you request parameters.

Comment: please hv a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22781969/adding-parameters-to-soap-request-using-ksoap2-android